# A word for a dumb person who pretends to be smart?

Tags: single-word-requests

Any word to describe someone who pretends to be sophisticated, smart and know-all but in reality is just so stupid to realize his/her stupidity because he/she always surrounded by likewise stupid people?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered.

Comment: There's something related to the Dunning Kruger effect, but I can't think of a single word for it.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect

Comment: 'Realty' has a different meaning. It should be 'reality' in this context.

Comment: @ArtyomLugovoy fixed!

Comment: Check out "anosognosia".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to comment but don't have enough status yet.

Your example person may be a Pseud.

Comment: That seems appropriate! Thanks

Comment: Is “pseud” short for “pseudo-intellectual”?